# How do I fix NoClassDefFoundError, the class path in the error is incorrect, but it's not in code I've written

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, noclassdeffounderror, jackson-databind

EDIT: Just realised it's caused by a `ClassNotFoundException`, would still like some help.

I'm trying to update keycloak from version `12.0.3`  to version `13.0.0`, however when I make that change I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/PolymorphicTypeValidator
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1651)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.util.PickConstructor.pickSingletonConstructor(PickConstructor.java:30)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createConstructorInjector(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2821)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2813)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.addMessageBodyReader(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1048)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1821)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:3026)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.register(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:559)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.register(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:48)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.newRestEasyClient(Keycloak.java:71)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:53)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder.build(KeycloakBuilder.java:147)
    at socsan.myapp.v1.mymodule.keycloak.KeycloakUserManager.createKeycloakInstance(KeycloakUserManager.java:187)
    at socsan.myapp.v1.mymodule.keycloak.KeycloakUserManager.<init>(KeycloakUserManager.java:36)
    at socsan.myapp.v1.mymodule.mymodule.startServices(mymodule.java:51)
    at socsan.myapp.common.lifecycle.ProcessStarter.runStartupTasks(ProcessStarter.java:61)
    at socsan.myapp.common.lifecycle.ProcessStarter.start(ProcessStarter.java:48)
    at socsan.myapp.v1.mymodule.mymodule.main(mymodule.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.PolymorphicTypeValidator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 20 more
```

I tried updating the fasterxml databind package too, but it didn't make any difference.

I noticed that the path to the correct jar in the maven repository is different to the path in the error.
In the maven repository there are stored at `com/fasterxml/jackson/core/databind`.
Does that have any baring on the issue?
How can I fix this?

EDIT 2:
In the parent pom we have this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The only change made to the module pom was to increase the version as stated above.

looking at the dependency analyser for `jackson-databind` it does look a bit of a mess, I should also point out that we're using the maven shade plugin:
[image: dependency analyser for jackson-databind package]

Comment: can please add you pom file details. what version you are using for fasterxml databind?

Comment: so it's the conflict between all these different version causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/PolymorphicTypeValidator.html) they have mentioned that PolymorphicTypeValidator is available from 2.10 but you are using 2.9.8